# Damaged and locked dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, battery

First of all I point out I'm not expert so sorry if I don't understand something or I write some silly stuff.
I downloaded the TLP for power saving while using my laptop with the battery, even though I never have the battery mounted since I usually keep my computer connected to the line.
I did it through the terminal but in the end I had a message saying the package has been downloaded but not installed because of some dependencies. I went through the package manager (I guess the name is correct) and it says there's a damaged package, the **Linux kernel version specific tools for version 3.13.0-53**
I tried to update it but there's nothing to do.
In another forum for Ubuntu, they asked me to type a kind of debug, I think.
Here it is:

```
leo@leo:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for leo:
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease                     
Trovato http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Scaricamento di:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                       
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg               
Trovato http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                               
Scaricamento di:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63,5 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release.gpg               
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                 
Trovato http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Trovato http://downloads.sourceforge.net all InRelease                         
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                       
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                 
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                   
Trovato http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Scaricamento di:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [80,7 kB]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                 
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages           
Scaricamento di:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]         
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages             
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages           
Scaricamento di:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2.061 B]
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-it               
Scaricamento di:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [25,2 kB]
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Scaricamento di:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2.335 B]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en               
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Scaricamento di:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [259 kB]
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-it         
Trovato http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main i386 Packages               
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en         
Scaricamento di:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release [15,1 kB]           
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-it         
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en         
Scaricamento di:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8.846 B]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-it           
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                               
Scaricamento di:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [104 kB]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en           
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources               
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-it_IT                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources           
Scaricamento di:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3.828 B]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-it                       
Trovato http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en         
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages         
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Trovato http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages     
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages   
Trovato http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en       
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                   
Trovato http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en     
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en 
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en   
Scaricamento di:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [18,4 kB]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages       
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages 
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages   
Scaricamento di:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [9.963 B]
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-it       
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en       
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-it
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-it
Trovato http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-it   
Trovato http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en   
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-it_IT                 
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-it_IT           
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-it_IT           
Ign http://it.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-it_IT             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-it_IT                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-it                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main Translation-it_IT               
Ign http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main Translation-it                   
Ign http://downloads.sourceforge.net all/main Translation-en                   
Recuperati 594 kB in 9s (62,7 kB/s)                                           
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Correzione delle dipendenze... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti saranno inoltre installati:
  linux-tools-common
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  linux-tools-common
0 aggiornati, 1 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 1 non aggiornati.
3 non completamente installati o rimossi.
È necessario scaricare 0 B/90,7 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 312 kB di spazio su disco.
Continuare? [S/n] s
(Lettura del database... 258639 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.88_all.deb...
Estrazione di linux-tools-common (3.13.0-53.88)...
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare l'archivio /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.88_all.deb (--unpack):
 tentata sovrascrittura di "/usr/share/man/man1/cpupower-info.1.gz" presente anche nel pacchetto linux-lts-vivid-tools-common 3.19.0-17.17~14.04.1
Elaborazione dei trigger per man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1)...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_3.13.0-53.88_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
leo@leo:~$
```

Some of the language is italian, so if you need to understand something just ask me. I would like to know if I can solve this problem without having to go back to the last configuration.
I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Thank you very much.

Comment: *tentata sovrascrittura di ... presente anche nel* (on the sixth line from the bottom of the code block)  translates to "trying to overwrite file, which is also in...".

Answer (score 0):

To have the messages in english, try

```
export LANG=C
```

before issuing the commands.

Seems that the packages `linux-tools-common` and `linux-lts-vivid-tools-common` are incompatible. Do you have some PPA enabled or some mix of different repository enabled?

I would try to remove the two packages above and repeat the installation (**check before removing them that no basic package is removed along them**) . Otherwise, add the output of:

```
apt-cache policy linux-lts-vivid-tools-common 
apt-cache policy linux-tools-common
```

to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove linux-tools-common again:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-tools-common
```

I suggest you report that you're affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-vivid/+bug/1455014